# How to display alerts as popup?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I saw examples about alerts here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ , nevertheless in that example alerts are just added into the current window.
I'd like to show a popup, so I'm using the $modal service..anyway as you can see from my plunker

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/Tz4SEvKft4EQoSDlZA2M`
```

some extra space shows up. How to remove it? And is this the only way to actually show an alert in angular ui?

Comment: What extra spaces? This is not an alert window. It's bootstrap modal window.

Comment: Yes, and the alert does not fully fill that modal window. I am not sure this is the best way, indeed...final result is similar to what I am trying to accomplish though

Comment: As you can see in the bootstrap css, there is "margin-bottom: 20px" on .alert class. You can remove that and then you have no spacing anymore.

Comment: mmm...I'd like to avoid altering bootstrap's css

Comment: You should override that value in your css.

Comment: Change template to:

      template: '<alert type="'+type+'" style="margin:0">'+msg+'</alert>'

Comment: Nice it works! I can mark your answer as correct if you actually answer